# How to set rotation on a certain axis

Tags: rotation, three.js

I am using the FlyControl, and I want it to always have the camera upright. If I look down, and then look left, the whole view is tilted however far I looked down. Just setting the euler order somehow doesn't seem to do it, because it's still messed up. I've been trying to research this for quite a bit and I've gotten nowhere.

How do I rotate the camera so it is upright, but still pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main app

```
camera.up = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
camera.rotation.order = "ZYX";
```

FlyControl.js:

```
this.update = function( delta ) {

    var moveMult = delta * this.movementSpeed * this.movementSpeedMultiplier;
    var rotMult = delta * this.rollSpeed;

    var cur = this.object.rotation;

    this.object.translateX( this.moveVector.x * moveMult );
    this.object.translateY( this.moveVector.y * moveMult );
    this.object.translateZ( this.moveVector.z * moveMult );

    //this.tmpQuaternion.set( this.rotationVector.x * rotMult, this.rotationVector.y * rotMult, this.rotationVector.z * rotMult, 1 ).normalize();
    //this.object.quaternion.multiply( this.tmpQuaternion );
    //this.object.lookAt(this.object.getWorldDirection())
    this.object.rotation.set( cur.x + this.rotationVector.x * rotMult, /*cur.y + this.rotationVector.y * rotMult*/ 0,  cur.z + this.rotationVector.y * rotMult, cur.order );
    console.log(this.rotationVector);
    // expose the rotation vector for convenience
    //this.object.rotation.setFromQuaternion( this.object.quaternion, this.object.rotation.order );


};
```